# Update property or create new element if it does not exist Lambda c#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have a large List<> of Name/Value pairs and need to be able to find if a particular Name exist in this list...if so update that Value, if NOT then create a new Name/Value pair and append it to my List.

What is the Lambda syntax to do this?

I have tried using .Where .DefaultIfEmpty but it just returns an empty object but does not append it to my original 'myList'

```
myList.Where(x => x.Name == 'some name').DefaultIfEmpty(new myobj(){ Name = 'some name').First().Value = 'some value';
```

I have to do this four multiple Names so if I had a simple syntax that would make it great =)

Comment: I am guessing that you are missing the myList.Add() in the code - myList.Where(x => x.Name == 'some name').DefaultIfEmpty(() => {myList.Add(new myobj(){ Name = 'some name').First().Value = 'some value'})};);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual query is just getting the first item that meets a condition.  LINQ is for *querying* not for modifying a collection, so you shouldn't be adding the item to the collection as a part of the query; do that as a part of processing the query.

```
var match = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "some name");
if(match != null)
    match.Value = "something else";
else
    list.Add(new MyObject(){...});
```

If you want a more generic `GetOrAdd` method you can make one as well:

```
public static T GetOrAdd<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate,
    Func<T> constructor)
{
    var match = list.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    if(match == null)
    {
        match = constructor();
        list.Add(match);
    }

    return match;
}
```

Using that you could write something like:

```
var item = list.GetOrAdd(obj => obj.Name == "Some Name", () => new MyObj(){...});
item.Value = "Some Value";
```

Having done that, please strongly consider using a `Dictionary` for this collection rather than a `List` of pairs as it can be much more efficiently searched based on the key.

If you did have a `Dictionary` then the code to do this would be as simple as:

```
dictionary["some name"] = "some value";
```

And in addition to being shorter in code, it will perform *dramatically* faster.

Comment: It isn't a true Name/Value pair collection, we have additional properties on the collection so unfortunately I am unable to use the dictionary approach...but thanks for the input =)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this extension method:

```
public static void UpdateOrAdd(this List<myobj> source, 
     string name, object value)
{
    var obj = source.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
    if (obj == null)
    {
        obj = new myobj { Name = name };
        source.Add(obj);
    }

    obj.Value = value;
}
```

Usage:

```
myList.UpdateOrAdd("some name", "some value");
```

But **consider to use dictionary**, as @Sam suggested.

Comment: If you're going to make an extension method out of it then you should genericize it.  If you're not going to genericize it then it's unlikely that it should be an extension method.

Comment: @Servy have you ever created extension methods for mapping between models and dto or viewmodels? Those extensions were generic? Also there is no benefit of generic, if you are going to search by item name and set its value. Constraints? :)

Comment: I'm not saying *all* extension methods should be generic.  I'm speaking to this one particular method.  If it's something that you think you're going to do a lot of, to the point that you want it to be an extension method, then it should probably be made generic as it wouldn't take that much to do.  If it's not generalized then I don't see this particular method being used often enough to warrant making an extension out of it.

Comment: I like this approach...I am thinking along the lines of making it more generic as well. We have several types of collections that we would benefit from this being a flexible extension method =) .. I like this approach tho @lazyberezovsky ... any thoughts on refactoring this to be more generic

Comment: @afreeland if you want something generic, then you will deal with constraints on generic parameter, or key and value selectors (lambdas), which will make your code hard to understand. I think best solution here is usage of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` to store key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

It just so happens that I *just* wrote this class for my own project, using a `Dictionary`:

```
public class CachedLoader<K, T> : Dictionary<K, T>
{
    private Func<K,T> GetItem = null;
    public CachedLoader(Func<K,T> getItem)
    {
        this.GetItem = getItem;
    }

    public new T this[K key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!base.ContainsKey(key)) base[key] = GetItem(key);
            return base[key];
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor takes a lambda expression to load the data.  You might use it like this:

```
CachedLoader<Guid, Employee> MOEmployees 
     = new CachedLoader<Guid, Employee>(id => EmployeeManager.List(id));
```

And you would consume it like this:

```
Guid employeeId = ...;
MOEmployees[employeeId]
```

There is no need to explicitly create/load the item from the code that you are consuming the data from because the class handles it for you - you just have to specify how to do it in the constructor.  You would adapt the constructor to create the value however you need it.

If you are stuck on a `List`, then you could easily adapt this to that structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultIfEmpty does not append to lists. It returns the specified value if the collection passed to it is empty. So in your case, nothing will happen because you're not assigning the result to anything; just allowing it to be discarded.

There's not a simple lambda chain to do what you want. You'll have to do two steps. First, you can see if there are any results that match what you're looking for, then append if not.

```
var defaultObj = new myobj() { Name = "default name", Value = "default value"};
if(!list.Any(x => x.Name == "some name")){
  list.Add(defaultObj);
}
```

Edit: in response to comment, I did miss updating the original. You could do something like this:

```
var obj = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "some name");
if(obj == null){
    obj = new myobj() { Name = "default name" };
    list.Add(obj);
} 
obj.Value = "some value";
```

Comment: This isn't changing the item with the given name if it already exists.

Comment: Tack on an else statement that does.

Comment: Then you're doing two linear searches through the list rather than one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any()`

```
if(list.Any(x => x.Name == "some name"))
{
    // Replace
}
else
{
    // Add
}
```

Comment: This is doing two linear searches through the collection to find it, once for the `Any` and once again in the `if` to edit it.